# How to conditionally update properties of items within a collection in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a collection of items stored in state:

```
this.state = {
    items: [
        { name: "foo", description: "a foo", index: 0 },
        { name: "bar", description: "a bar", index: 1 },
        { name: "herp", description: "a herp", index: 2 },
        { name: "derp", description: "a derp", index: 3 }
    ]
};
```

The `index` property represents the ordinal position of each item in the collection. At some point I need to re-order these items. For example, "derp" may need to be moved to the front, so the indices of the other items need to be updated:

```
{ name: "derp", description: "a derp", index: 0 },
{ name: "bar", description: "a bar", index: 1 },
{ name: "herp", description: "a herp", index: 2 },
{ name: "foo", description: "a foo", index: 3 }
```

I am currently updating the state using `update` from the `immutability-helper` package. However, I am certain this is not the correct way to do it (although it works):

```
// originalIndex is a variable holding the original index
// newIndex is a variable holding the new index

// initialise updatedItems so we can update within the loop
let updatedItems = update(this.state.items, { [originalIndex]: {'index': {$set: newIndex}}});

for (var i = newIndex; i < this.state.items.length; i++) {
    if (i !== originalIndex) {
        updatedItems = update(updatedItems, { [i]: {'index': {set$: parseInt(this.state.items[i].index) + 1}}});
    }
}
```

This feels like a massive hack.

My question is, is it possible to call update with conditional logic, and so can this loop be replaced with a single call to update?

Comment: Seems a bit hacky for `index` to be a property inside each object, if all it really refers to is the index in the items array.

Comment: Ditto what @TomFenech said.  No need for index property _within_ an when an element can be _directly_ referred to by it's index in the array

Comment: That's actually a good point! I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: So if we drop the `index` property, does each item remain an object with a `name` property or do you now just have a list of strings?

Comment: @TomFenech Each item is still an object. I actually just updated the question as based on your answer it was clear I had oversimplified it too much. My actual objects contain 4 properties in addition to index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that we pull the `index` property out of each item, you can create the new list like this:

```
const items = this.state.items.slice();
const value = items[oldIndex];
items.splice(oldIndex, 1);         // remove the one you want to move
items.splice(newIndex, 0, value);  // add it back to the desired index

this.setState({ items });
```

That is, use slice to make a (shallow) copy of the list, then use splice to swap the elements around.

Since you're only moving one element at a time, you can save a line using:

```
const [value] = items.splice(oldIndex, 1);
```

This assigns the first element of the array returned by `splice` to `value`.

If you want to keep `index` (why?), then you need to reassign the indices:

```
this.setState({ items: items.map((item, index) => ({ ...item, index })) });
```

Comment: Thanks Tom. I agree that in hindsight including the index in the objects is pointless. I'll give this a shot tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Why not sort the item before hand, on render() :

```
render(){
    let toDisplay = this.state.items.sort( (a,b) => {
        if (a.index <= b.index) {
           return -1;
        }
        if (a.index > b.index) {
           return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    });

    return(
         <div className='foo'>
            {
                toDisplay.map((item, i) => {
                    return(
                        <div className="bar" key={i}>{ item.name }</div>
                    );
                })
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Then you can update the state.items only by using :

```
this.setState({
    items: yourUpdatedItems
});
```

Comment: Because JavaScript's `sort` modifies its receiver, this code will mutate `this.state`, which the React docs strongly caution against. You probably want to do `let toDisplay = this.state.items.slice().sort(...)` to instead operate on a copy of the array.